# How can I get missing apps back after factory resetting my rooted x10 Mini?

Tags: google-play-store, link2sd, factory-reset, sony-xperia-x10-mini

I rooted my Sony Ericsson xperia x10 mini and linked my apps to my sd card using link2sd, I then factory reset my phone from the android privacy settings.

superuser still exists on my phone

1. how do I get my linked apps to become visible and usable?
2. my Android Market has the (killing me) "starting download" forever (and I don't have GTalk, Google Talk that I was told I need to resolve this.) I've tried both wifi and SIM data connection

I've tried clearing market cache+data and nothing

I can't access my memory card because I can't download link2sd and I cant use the Market.

I want my phone to show my linked apps and for the market to work

If you need more info please don't hesitate to ask...

Answer (score 1):

Are you running a custom ROM on your Xperia x10 mini? If you are missing the Google Talk app, this means that factory rest deleted some of the Google apps required for Market to work properly. I would suggest finding the appropriate GApps package for the ROM you are running and re-flashing it.

Comment: Im not running a cutom ROM. So how do i get the GApps package and re-flash it?

Comment: And is there a way to find out what ROM im using?

Answer (score 0):

What i done is i found a programme called "Android injector" which installs .apk files from your pc to your android. Downloaded and installed the google apps and that sorted the market problem out. but i ddnt get to keep my old apps after i got link to sd it was blank. oh well....

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the factory reset removed the changes that link2sd made. but if you now moved apps that are system apps (like talk) they are now "gone". I am not 100% sure how link2sd works, if it uses an ext3 partition on the sdcard or what exactly it does. But it sounds like it really botched up your system.

Your best bet at this point it to [find the Stock ROM](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=9067949&postcount=1) and reflash the device back to the original stock setup.

For future reference, a factory reset does not return the device to "stock setup", it deletes all the user data off the device, as if it has never been used. It does not add any system apps or reset their "state". If you make those kinds of changes, a factory reset does not fix them.